# Can't save mongo objectId to session with expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I'm learning to use express with node and mongo at the moment, and am struggling with creating  a user ID and saving it to the session.  Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.cookieParser('mysecret'));
app.use(express.session());

var port = 3000;

var databaseUrl = 'chat';
var collections = ["users", "messages"];
var db = require('mongojs').connect(databaseUrl, collections);
var users = db.collection('users');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.userId);//always undefined
    if (req.session.userId){
        userId = req.session.userId;
        console.log('has userid in session');//never appears
        console.log(userId);
    }else{
        users.insert({ip: req.ip}, function(err, docs){
            if (err) return;
            userId = docs[0]._id;
            req.session.userId = userId;
            console.log(req.session.userId);//always shows the new generated id
        });
    }

    res.render("page");
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.userId){
        console.log(req.session.userId);
    }else{
        req.session.userId = 'asdfmi34qoprjifd';
    }
    res.send('Saved a value to req.session.userId');
});
```

My intention is that if you visit "/", a user record (at the moment with nothing but your IP address) will be created in Mongo, and the ID will be saved to session.  This doesn't seem to work properly.

Every time you visit "/", it creates a new record in the DB.  The first call to `console.log(req.session.userId)` always shows "undefined".

The strange thing is, if you visit "/test", it saves the value fine, and you can then go back to "/" and it will show you the value it saved at "/test".

Any pointers, invitations to RTFM (with links to the FM), very welcome :).  Have checked the express examples on github for using sessions and am still none the wiser.

Comment: I think you should pass the secret to the call to .session(), rather than .cookieParser(). See if this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks - that's not the problem, sessions are working as I can save to the session in the "/test" route, just not in the "/" route.

Answer (score 0):

looking at  http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession you need

`app.use(express.cookieSession());` not express.session()